# Reference of drawable and drawable idrtl in Android Studio in DevEco?

Tags: android-studio, huawei-mobile-services, harmonyos, deveco-studio

Are 'drawable' and 'drawable Idrtl' under "res" in Android Studio the same as "graphic under resources" in DevEco Studio ? Below Attached images are as references:

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No not exactly

1. drawable in Android Studio can contain both images and selector/custom background xml files.
2. On the other hand in DevEco Studio, graphic directory will contain selector/custom background xml files while media directory will contain image files.

[image]